# Multiselect option onChange with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, multi-select

I have the following MySql table:

```
id | type      | mark      | model | series  | year
1    worldwide  NULL         NULL    NULL      NULL
2    1          Acura        NULL    NULL      NULL
3    1          2            NSX     NULL      NULL
4    1          2            3       TunedUp   2000-2003
5    1          2            3       & nbsp    2004-2005
```

I would like to create a select choice of four stages dependent from one another. For example, choose `Sports`, the second field select choose `Acura`, the third `NSX` and the fourth `TunedUP (2000 - 2003)` or `& nbsp; (2004 - 2005)`.

I found the following solution with [JavaScript ToolBox Dynamic Option List](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/dynamicoptionlist/examples.php), but it shows me a lot of `NULL`values. I'm looking for a simpler solution. I've tried googling, but I can not even properly describe my problem.

Comment: google `cascading select` or `cascading dropdown`

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Create table country */
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

/*create table state*/
CREATE TABLE `state` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `countryid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `statename` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

/* Create table city */
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `city` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `stateid` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  `countryid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

Now to test the demo in working we have to add some records in each of the tables. So run the following queries to add the records.

```
/* Inserting records into country table */
INSERT INTO `country` VALUES (1, 'USA');
INSERT INTO `country` VALUES (2, 'Canada');

/* Inserting records into state table */
INSERT INTO `state` VALUES (1, 1, 'New York');
INSERT INTO `state` VALUES (2, 1, 'Los Angeles');
INSERT INTO `state` VALUES (3, 2, 'British Columbia');
INSERT INTO `state` VALUES (4, 2, 'Torentu');

/* Inserting records into city table */
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (1, 'Los Angales', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (2, 'New York', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (3, 'Toranto', 4, 2);
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (4, 'Vancovour', 3, 2);
```

Now make one file index.php and paste the below code.

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1"> 
<center>
<table width="45%"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td width="75">Country</td>
      <td width="50">:</td>
      <td  width="150">
      <select name="country" onChange="getState(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select Country</option>
 <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
 <option value=<?php echo $row['id']?>><?php echo $row['country']?></option>
 <?php } ?>
     </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr style="">
    <td>State</td>
    <td width="50">:</td>
    <td >
 <div id="statediv">
        <select name="state" >
        <option>Select State</option>
        </select>
 </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td width="50">:</td>
    <td >
 <div id="citydiv">
          <select name="city">
          <option>Select City</option>

           </select>

         </div>

    </td>

  </tr>
  </table>
</center>
</form>
```

In the onChage event of the country drop down we have called getState() function of the javascript. Which change the options values of the State drop down, let’s look at the code the getState() function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getState(countryId) { 
    var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  if (req) {
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) {      
      document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
      document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML='<select name="city">'+
      '<option>Select City</option>'+'</select>';      
     } else {
      alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }  
 }
<script>
```

As you can see in the above code we are passing the countryid to the file findState.php, which populate the options in the drop down of the state which is fetched from Ajax , is given below.

```
<?php $country=intval($_GET['country']); 
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('test');
$query="SELECT id,statename FROM state WHERE countryid='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?php echo $country?>,this.value)">
<option>Select State</option>
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['id']?>><?php echo $row['statename']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

In the above code for the state dropdown, getCity() function is called on its  onChage event having parameters countryId and stateId, now let’s look at the code of the getCity() function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function getCity(countryId,stateId) {   
      var strURL="findCity.php?country="+countryId+"&state="+stateId;
      var req = getXMLHTTP();

      if (req) {

       req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
         // only if "OK"
         if (req.status == 200) {      
          document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;      
         } else {
          alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
         }
        }    
       }   
       req.open("GET", strURL, true);
       req.send(null);
      }

     }
```

As you can see in the above ajax function, one file findcity.php is called and this PHP file populate the city dropdown according to the supplied parameters country and state from get method. Now let’s look at the code of findcity.php,

```
<?php 
$countryId = intval($_GET['country']); 
$stateId   = intval($_GET['state']);
$con       = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('test');
$query="SELECT id,city FROM city WHERE countryid='$countryId' AND stateid='$stateId'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="city">
<option>Select City</option>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['id']?>><?php echo $row['city']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice solution. 
But at the beginning I forgot to add - I have to rely on the available database (presented table). There is already added so much data that they re-rewriting will take me at least a couple of weeks ...

Comment: can you modify the existing code instead of recreating new DB ?

Comment: I will try :-) But its quite hard for my skills level

Comment: i am not getting your code the way you have written please give me your table structure i'll try with my code  to give you solution.

Comment: I am sending a sample. The structure is not beautiful, but it is written by the company from which I purchased the license with updates for the coming years. I could convert it to the structure of "id, name, parent," but records after yesterday's update is over 101k, and I would add a lot of work. On the margin. I just do not know if I would cope with the structure "id, name, parent". [link](http://p.shrib.com/MqVQzh7R)    Thank you very much for existing and future help!